# Why are my navbar options/buttons stacking on top of each other?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Earlier I changed something to my CSS and messed with the class/ID for my navbar for my page and it lead to the buttons stacking on top of each other... Can anyone figure out what's wrong or how I can fix this?

I included my code and a picture of what's going on... I've toyed around with it but to no avail... Also some stuff in my CSS is empty because I'm still working on it.

Thanks so much.

[Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcpGH.png)

```css
html {
  background-color: #85BDA6;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  
}

#header-2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#header-5 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#header-6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  padding-top: 50px;
 
}

#pricing {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block
   
}

#email {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

#submit {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  
}

#email {
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
}

#submit {
  height: 30px;
}

#nav-bar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: grey;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav-link {
font-size: 23px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: flex;
justify-content: end;
display: inline;
right: 0;
color: white;
opacity: 1;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bi bi-truck {

    display: block;
    margin: auto;    
}

.bi bi-emoji-smile {
  
}

.about-us {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.long-distance {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px;) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
    <body>
      <main>
        <header id="header"> Chirila & Co.
          
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-options">
  <a href="#header-2" class="nav-link">About Us |</a> 
  <a href="#header-3" class="nav-link">Services |</a> 
  <a href="#header-6" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
          </nav>          
        </header>
        <div style="text-align: center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-truck" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 2h9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 12 3.5V5h1.02a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.17.563l1.481 1.85a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .329.938V10.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5H14a2 2 0 1 1-4 0H5a2 2 0 1 1-3.998-.085A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 10.5v-7zm1.294 7.456A1.999 1.999 0 0 1 4.732 11h5.536a2.01 2.01 0 0 1 .732-.732V3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .294.456zM12 10a2 2 0 0 1 1.732 1h.768a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V8.35a.5.5 0 0 0-.11-.312l-1.48-1.85A.5.5 0 0 0 13.02 6H12v4zm-9 1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm9 0a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
</svg>
        </div>   
        <h2 id="header-2">About Us</h2>
        
        <p class="about-us">Chirila & Co. is a moving company that was born out of the COVID-19 pandemic that started in late 2019. Since the company started, we have provided our services to hundreds of individuals and families that have moved whether it was down around the block or across the country. Our company prides itself in operating with integrity, affordability, flexbility, and great service. We acknowledge that hiring a moving company can really be a hit or miss. We want our clients and prospects to know we are a company that you can count on and trust to move your possessions in a safe and swift manner.</p>
        
<div style="text-align: center">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-emoji-smile" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
  <path d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
        
        
<h3 id="header-3">Services</h3>
        
        
        <h4 id="header-4">Local Moving</h4>
        
<p>Whether its around the block or across the state, our company will assist you in moving your possessions and transporting them to your new residence or space. 
  
        <h5 id="header-5"> Long-Distance Moving</h5>
        
<p class="long-distance">Want to move your possessions to a residence or space out of state? Maybe across the country? Not a problem. Our company offers services for long-distance moving as well. From LA to New York or from Florida to Washington, we got you covered.</p>
        
<div style="text-align: center">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 10a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"/>
  <path d="M0 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v8a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4zm3 0a2 2 0 0 1-2 2v4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2H3z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
        
<h6 id="header-6">Pricing</h6>
        
<p id="pricing">With Chirila & Co. we pride ourselves on flexibility and affordability. Pricing depends on various factors such as how many moving trucks may be needed and how far your new residence may be. Submit your email at the bottom of the page and we'll get one of our team members to contact you within 1 business day to discuss your situation and give you a quote. Don't worry, you're in good hands.</p>
        
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
  

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eiGZZCOy7Yo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
      
        <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
  <div class="input">
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." required>
      
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
            
          </div>
     </form>
        
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js">
```

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then add `display: inline-block;` to `.nav-link`

Comment: I tried that it did not work :( I tried it also for the class I assigned for the navigation bar

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache

Comment: I tried that... it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `display: inline-block;` on `.nav-link` to make them adjust to their content width. Block elements take up the whole row unless you set their width manually. Additionally, to manually override your imported styles, use `display: inline-block !important;`.

```css
html {
  background-color: #85BDA6;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  
}

#header-2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#header-5 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#header-6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  padding-top: 50px;
 
}

#pricing {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block
   
}

#email {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

#submit {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  
}

#email {
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
}

#submit {
  height: 30px;
}

#nav-bar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: grey;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav-link {
font-size: 23px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block !important;
color: white;
opacity: 1;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bi bi-truck {

    display: block;
    margin: auto;    
}

.bi bi-emoji-smile {
  
}

.about-us {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.long-distance {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px;) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
    <body>
      <main>
        <header id="header"> Chirila & Co.
          
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav-options">
  <a href="#header-2" class="nav-link">About Us |</a> 
  <a href="#header-3" class="nav-link">Services |</a> 
  <a href="#header-6" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
          </nav>          
        </header>
        <div style="text-align: center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-truck" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 2h9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 12 3.5V5h1.02a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.17.563l1.481 1.85a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .329.938V10.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5H14a2 2 0 1 1-4 0H5a2 2 0 1 1-3.998-.085A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 10.5v-7zm1.294 7.456A1.999 1.999 0 0 1 4.732 11h5.536a2.01 2.01 0 0 1 .732-.732V3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .294.456zM12 10a2 2 0 0 1 1.732 1h.768a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V8.35a.5.5 0 0 0-.11-.312l-1.48-1.85A.5.5 0 0 0 13.02 6H12v4zm-9 1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm9 0a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
</svg>
        </div>   
        <h2 id="header-2">About Us</h2>
        
        <p class="about-us">Chirila & Co. is a moving company that was born out of the COVID-19 pandemic that started in late 2019. Since the company started, we have provided our services to hundreds of individuals and families that have moved whether it was down around the block or across the country. Our company prides itself in operating with integrity, affordability, flexbility, and great service. We acknowledge that hiring a moving company can really be a hit or miss. We want our clients and prospects to know we are a company that you can count on and trust to move your possessions in a safe and swift manner.</p>
        
<div style="text-align: center">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-emoji-smile" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
  <path d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
        
        
<h3 id="header-3">Services</h3>
        
        
        <h4 id="header-4">Local Moving</h4>
        
<p>Whether its around the block or across the state, our company will assist you in moving your possessions and transporting them to your new residence or space. 
  
        <h5 id="header-5"> Long-Distance Moving</h5>
        
<p class="long-distance">Want to move your possessions to a residence or space out of state? Maybe across the country? Not a problem. Our company offers services for long-distance moving as well. From LA to New York or from Florida to Washington, we got you covered.</p>
        
<div style="text-align: center">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 10a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"/>
  <path d="M0 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v8a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4zm3 0a2 2 0 0 1-2 2v4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2H3z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
        
<h6 id="header-6">Pricing</h6>
        
<p id="pricing">With Chirila & Co. we pride ourselves on flexibility and affordability. Pricing depends on various factors such as how many moving trucks may be needed and how far your new residence may be. Submit your email at the bottom of the page and we'll get one of our team members to contact you within 1 business day to discuss your situation and give you a quote. Don't worry, you're in good hands.</p>
        
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
  

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eiGZZCOy7Yo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
      
        <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
  <div class="input">
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." required>
      
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
            
          </div>
     </form>
        
<script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js">
```

Comment: I tried that... it did not work, I also tried it for the class I assigned for the navigation bar.

Comment: It looks like you need to mark the change as `!important` to override the default styles in your imported Bootstrap stylesheet. I updated my answer with the change.

Comment: That worked!! But now the buttons in my navbar are weirdly spaced out...

Comment: `padding: 0.5rem 0 !important;`

Comment: I love it... thank you so much, you've been a great help

Answer (score 1):

Let bootstrap do the work for you.  Just add the class nav to #nav-bar

```css
html {
  background-color: #85BDA6;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  
}

#header-2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#header-4 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#header-5 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#header-6 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  padding-top: 50px;
 
}

#pricing {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

p {
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 1.7;
  text-align: center;
}

#video {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   display: block
   
}

#email {
  display: inline-block;
  
}

#submit {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  
}

#email {
  width: 20%;
  height: 25px;
}

#submit {
  height: 30px;
}

#nav-bar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-color: grey;
padding-bottom: 10px;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav-link {
font-size: 23px;
padding-top: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: flex;
justify-content: end;
display: inline;
right: 0;
color: white;
opacity: 1;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.bi bi-truck {

    display: block;
    margin: auto;    
}

.bi bi-emoji-smile {
  
}

.about-us {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.long-distance {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 500px;) {
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
    <body>
      <main>
        <header id="header"> Chirila & Co.
          
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="nav nav-options">
  <a href="#header-2" class="nav-link">About Us |</a> 
  <a href="#header-3" class="nav-link">Services |</a> 
  <a href="#header-6" class="nav-link">Pricing</a>
          </nav>          
        </header>
        <div style="text-align: center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-truck" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M0 3.5A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.5 2h9A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 12 3.5V5h1.02a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.17.563l1.481 1.85a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 .329.938V10.5a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-1.5 1.5H14a2 2 0 1 1-4 0H5a2 2 0 1 1-3.998-.085A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 0 10.5v-7zm1.294 7.456A1.999 1.999 0 0 1 4.732 11h5.536a2.01 2.01 0 0 1 .732-.732V3.5a.5.5 0 0 0-.5-.5h-9a.5.5 0 0 0-.5.5v7a.5.5 0 0 0 .294.456zM12 10a2 2 0 0 1 1.732 1h.768a.5.5 0 0 0 .5-.5V8.35a.5.5 0 0 0-.11-.312l-1.48-1.85A.5.5 0 0 0 13.02 6H12v4zm-9 1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm9 0a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z"/>
</svg>
        </div>   
        <h2 id="header-2">About Us</h2>
        
        <p class="about-us">Chirila & Co. is a moving company that was born out of the COVID-19 pandemic that started in late 2019. Since the company started, we have provided our services to hundreds of individuals and families that have moved whether it was down around the block or across the country. Our company prides itself in operating with integrity, affordability, flexbility, and great service. We acknowledge that hiring a moving company can really be a hit or miss. We want our clients and prospects to know we are a company that you can count on and trust to move your possessions in a safe and swift manner.</p>
        
<div style="text-align: center">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-emoji-smile" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 15A7 7 0 1 1 8 1a7 7 0 0 1 0 14zm0 1A8 8 0 1 0 8 0a8 8 0 0 0 0 16z"/>
  <path d="M4.285 9.567a.5.5 0 0 1 .683.183A3.498 3.498 0 0 0 8 11.5a3.498 3.498 0 0 0 3.032-1.75.5.5 0 1 1 .866.5A4.498 4.498 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.498 4.498 0 0 1-3.898-2.25.5.5 0 0 1 .183-.683zM7 6.5C7 7.328 6.552 8 6 8s-1-.672-1-1.5S5.448 5 6 5s1 .672 1 1.5zm4 0c0 .828-.448 1.5-1 1.5s-1-.672-1-1.5S9.448 5 10 5s1 .672 1 1.5z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
        
        
<h3 id="header-3">Services</h3>
        
        
        <h4 id="header-4">Local Moving</h4>
        
<p>Whether its around the block or across the state, our company will assist you in moving your possessions and transporting them to your new residence or space. 
  
        <h5 id="header-5"> Long-Distance Moving</h5>
        
<p class="long-distance">Want to move your possessions to a residence or space out of state? Maybe across the country? Not a problem. Our company offers services for long-distance moving as well. From LA to New York or from Florida to Washington, we got you covered.</p>
        
<div style="text-align: center">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="70" height="70" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-cash" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M8 10a2 2 0 1 0 0-4 2 2 0 0 0 0 4z"/>
  <path d="M0 4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h14a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v8a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H1a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V4zm3 0a2 2 0 0 1-2 2v4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 1 2-2V6a2 2 0 0 1-2-2H3z"/>
</svg>
        </div>
        
<h6 id="header-6">Pricing</h6>
        
<p id="pricing">With Chirila & Co. we pride ourselves on flexibility and affordability. Pricing depends on various factors such as how many moving trucks may be needed and how far your new residence may be. Submit your email at the bottom of the page and we'll get one of our team members to contact you within 1 business day to discuss your situation and give you a quote. Don't worry, you're in good hands.</p>
        
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
  

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eiGZZCOy7Yo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe>
      
        <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit" id="form">
  <div class="input">
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email..." required>
      
<input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
            
          </div>
     </form>
        
 <!--   <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js">-->
```